# Como descobrir o tipo de dado de um arquivo binário

Tags: c++, binary

Um problema que enfrento frequentemente é descobrir que tipo de dado usar para armazenar o conteúdo de um arquivo binário. Por exemplo quando eu inicio um projeto de uma emulador mais simples como CHIP8 ou Gameboy, geralmente eu uso um tipo de dado com valor de 8-Bits como `unsigned char` ou `std::uint8_t` pois sei que os jogos dessa época eram em geral 8-Bits.

Mas quando se trata de um console mais "recente" por exemplo um Nitendo 64? Esse é mais complexo pois pelo que já pesquisei, existe vários tipos de ROMs desse formato com dados diferentes como Big Endians e Low Endians, então como eu posso fazer para descobrir qual o tipo mais adequado para armazenar essas ROM ou qualquer outra ROM de qualquer outro console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De maneira genérica, formato de header não tem jeito, ou você conhece, ou você descobre por tentativa e erro.

E respondendo ao seu comentário, você pode armazenar variáveis como quiser... isso tudo vai depender de como você está implementando o seu emulador. O ponto chave é se você está pegando as informações corretas do header. Uma vez coletadas, armazene como julgar necessário/pertinente.

O interessante é você armazenar sempre de maneira eficiente para não ter overhead de memória e além disso, igualar os tamanhos das variáveis pode ser que facilite o desenvolvimento do emulador uma vez que os tamanhos do sistema do emulador batendo com o do dispositivo pode facilitar "navegar" na ROM e/ou no "kernel" do emulador.

Answer (score 1):

Isso pode variar muito. Não há um padrão. Cada arquivo de imagem possui um *layout* diferente e isso vai depender muito de cada plataforma/arquitetura, veja só:

**SEGA/Genesis**: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Genesis_Programming#ROM_header

**NES**: https://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/INES#iNES_file_format

Comment: Pesquisei mais um pouco sobre headers do n64 e vi que o que geralmente muda é a ordem dos bytes (Algo que vou ter que estudar para melhor compreender), no caso, os tipos de dados podem causar diferença na leitura? Por exemplo, se eu armazenar uma ROM de Gameboy em um tipo de 64 Bits (ou vice versa), poderia ocorrer de ler um dado de forma errada?